# How to limit decimal values based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an amount field which is `decimal(13,5)` in `SQl Server.`

So it takes values like `22.23456` (5 values after decimals)

Now i want to limit the decimal places based on condition like below:

for `22.23456`, result should be `22.24`

for `22.20001`, result should be `22.21`

for `22.20000`, result should be `22.20`

for `22.00000`, result should be `22.00`

So if there is any number other than 0 after 2nd decimal place(in 1st ex:4),just increase the value 2nd decimal value by 1.(`22.2345` to `22.24`)

Is there any  function or do we need to use length type functions to achieve this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the highest value in the hundredths position using standard rounding will not work. You can however use a little math and CEILING to accomplish.

```
with MyValues(SomeValue) as
(
    select 22.23456 union all
    select 22.20001 union all
    select 22.20000 union all
    select 22.00000 
)
select cast(ceiling(SomeValue * 100) / 100. as numeric(9,2)) as MyResult
from MyValues
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx

Comment: Thanks much @Sean.This helped me.